# python too many values to unpack error and blank output

Tags: python

I lost my previous account id so I am starting new.

```
templist=[]
temps1=[]
templist2=[]
tempstat1={}
station1={}
station2={}
import os.path



def main():

#file name=animallog.txt

endofprogram=False 
try:
    filename=input("Enter name of input file >")
    file=open(filename,"r")
except IOError:
    print("File does not exist")
    endofprogram=True
count=0
count2=0

for line in file:
    line=line.strip('\n')

    if (len(line)!=0)and line[0]!='#':

        (x,y,z)=line.split(':')
        templist.append((x,y,z))
        record=(x,z)
        temps1.append(record)

        for x,y in record:

            if x in station1 or station2:
                if y=='s1':
                    station1[x]=station1[x]+1
                elif y=='s2':
                    station2[x]=station2[x]+1

            elif x not in station1 and station2:
                if y=='s1':
                    station1[x]=1
                elif y=='s2':
                    station2[x]=1


main()
```

Anyways guys. I wrote this program. It is basically reading a file that has info like this->
(animal:date:station number)

```
a01:01-24-2011:s1

a03:01-24-2011:s2

a03:09-24-2011:s1
```

I am trying to count which animal goes to which station and how many times. I do not want an answer from you experts but just need to know what this ERROR means-

```
File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 58, in <module>
File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 39, in main

builtins.ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Thank you :)

**EDIT--**

changed `for x,y in record:` *TO* `for x in record:`

But it prints `{}` when I try to print `station1` and `station2`

Why is it printing blank dictionaries for `station1` and `station2`?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: `and` and `or` do not work the way you think they do.  They need a boolean expression on either side.  Empty dictionaries always evaluate `False`, dictionaries with contents (no matter what they are) evaluate `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`record` is a 2-tuple of strings. By iterating over `record` specifying a 2-tuple you are attempting to split each of these strings into 2 variables.

**This will not work unless they are two-character strings.**

Perhaps you meant to iterate over `temps1` instead?

Comment: Ok! I get it now. Temps1 is only for animals who went to station1. Perhaps now that I have the solution. I need to refine my code!

Comment: Is blank dictionaries that are being printed also because of this?

Comment: They're empty because `y` never matches anything.

Comment: Got it @Ignacio ! Refining my code and already getting better :)